# How to input decimal numbers and auto format with thousand separators at the same time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, type-conversion

I am currently trying to make an input that will take in decimal numbers and will auto format with thousand separators at the same time.

However, the only I can do auto format thousand separator is to set input type='text', which I cannot enter decimal numbers. Where as setting input type='number' allows me to input decimal number but it won't auto format with thousand separators

Here is the code:

```
<input
  className="cal__section__form__container--input"
  placeholder={0}
  type="text"
  value={displayVal || ""}
  onChange={(e) => {
    const targ = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "") || 0;
    const displayVal = parseFloat(targ).toLocaleString(undefined, {
       maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      });
      console.log(displayVal);
      
   }}
```

/>

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly. Are you wanting to take a number like 4 and have it say `4.000`? Or something like `4.24524858403` to `4.245`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to enter like 4000000.12 and display it as 4,000,000.12. But right now I can only enter either 4000000.12, or get 4,000,000

Comment: Ah ok. Yulian's answer seems to cover it.

Answer (score 5):

You're never updating your displayVal state. It's also good practice to handle your event logic outside of onChange. Here's how your code should look:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const clean = value.replace(/,/g, "");
    const regex = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/;

    if (value && clean.match(regex)) {
      if (!value.includes(".")) {
        const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(clean));
        setDisplayVal(formatted);
      } else {
        setDisplayVal(value);
      }
    } else {
      setDisplayVal("");
    }
};

<input
    className="cal__section__form__container--input"
    placeholder={0}
    type="text"
    value={displayVal}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Hey sorry I didnt paste all my code because there is a lot more logic behind it. But I do have a usestate thats saving my values, the problem is just that I cannot get a thousand separator formatted input with decimal numbers

Comment: I updated my answer. It's not perfect, but works for your case.

Comment: @I0_ol that breaks the function. The value of the input is a string, not a number. The conversion is necessary since he wants to format the actual value in the input. It has to be a string to display commas. The clean is also necessary otherwise you're passing commas into the number formatter. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-surf-rncxz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You're right. My mistake.

Comment: @Yulian For some reason when I type something in the input and delete it I get a values.includes is not a function error. And is there a way I can limit the input to not being able to enter letters?

Comment: I updated my answer, it now only allows digits and periods, and solves the NaN issue.

Comment: Not working for reactstrap comonents and they say you should use only defaultValue for setting the value at first render so how can I achieve having the formatted value dynamically?

https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/593